# Linker error: "undefined reference to class constructor"

Tags: linker

I'm trying to build my program. My program uses a class and creates instances of it. while building my program I get linker error "undefined reference to class constructor". However the component in which the constructor definition is present has been included as a static library dependency and it is even present in "/usr/lib/" folder. The static library even contains the required symbols. But I'm still not able to resolve the "undefined reference" error

Comment: Q: What language? C++?  Q: Are you #includ'ing the correct header(s)?  Q: Are you sure it's a "linker" error (and not a compile error)?  Q: Could you cut/paste the exact error text?

Comment: Language is C++. It is a linker error. the error looks like this.  undefined reference to `classname::classname(classname const&)' . It is able to locate the header as it compiles successfully, it is not able to find the definition, though I have given the library which which it is present

Comment: how do you pass the static library? remember the order is important

Comment: I tried re-ordering the libs. But couldnt resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you've a cpp file with implementation of your <%classname%>. If so, I think you've missed to register this cpp-file in your build system. When linker tries to resolve referencies on your <%classname%>'s member function(s) and constructor(s) it may issue a error if it won't find related implementation( here I mean compiled assembly-code routine ), because it wasn't compiled.